# Convert Base64 byte[] to readable String in java

Tags: java, base64

I want to convert Base62 Byte array to human readable Stiring

In this code,

I need to convert "[B@913fe2"(the result) to "Hello Wold!".

I viewd several former questions but I don't know how.

```
package chapter9;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;

/**
 * Example of generating a detached signature.
 */
public class SignedDataExample
    extends SignedDataProcessor
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore        credentials = Utils.createCredentials();
        PrivateKey      key = (PrivateKey)credentials.getKey(Utils.END_ENTITY_ALIAS, Utils.KEY_PASSWD);
    Certificate[]   chain = credentials.getCertificateChain(Utils.END_ENTITY_ALIAS);
    CertStore       certsAndCRLs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
                        new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Arrays.asList(chain)), "BC");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[0];

    // set up the generator
    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    gen.addSigner(key, cert, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA256);
    gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certsAndCRLs);

    // create the signed-data object

    CMSProcessable  data = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello World!".getBytes());
    //CMSProcessable  data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data1.getBytes());

    CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(data, "BC");

    // recreate
    signed = new CMSSignedData(data, signed.getEncoded());

    //signed.signedContent
    //signed.g
    CMSProcessable S = signed.getSignedContent();
    byte[] K = Base64.decodeBase64((S.getContent()).toString());
    //String K = Base64.decodeBase64(S.getContent());
    //BASE64Decoder.decoder.decodeBuffer()

    // verification step
    X509Certificate rootCert = (X509Certificate)credentials.getCertificate(Utils.ROOT_ALIAS);

    if (isValid(signed, rootCert))
    {
        System.out.println("verification succeeded");
        System.out.println(K);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("verification failed");
    }
}
```

}

### again, the result shows

verification succeeded

### [B@913fe2

I need to convert "[B@913fe2"(the result) to "Hello Wold!".

regards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `toString()` on a byte array just prints the type of the array (`[B`) followed by its hashCode. You want to use `new String(byteArray)`.

You should also consider using an explicit charset instead of the default one:

```
byte[] array = string.getBytes("UTF8");
String s = new String(array, "UTF8");
```

Comment: It's hard to tell why, because we don't know what your CMSXxx objects do, what the types of `S.getContent()` is, and where Base64 is used to encode. Try to experiment with just strings, byte arrays and base64 encoding/decoding. Then add crypto.

Comment: Thanks, JB Nizet. You don't need to know  CMSXxx objects as well as S.getContent(). All I need to do is to convert [B@eb7859 to Hellow World!

Comment: You can't. Because if you read my answer again, and try to understand it, you'll finally understand that [B@eb7859 doesn't represent anything meaningful. What you need to transform into a STring is a byte array. [B@eb7859 is just the type and hashCode of the byte array. Stop calling `toString()` or printing byte arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
byte[] k = Base64.decodeBase64((S.getContent()).toString());
String asString = new String(k);
```

Comment: it fails to convert to String

Comment: On the first line or on the second?

Comment: What is `S.getContent().toString()`? I tested my code with a valid base64 string ("SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==") and it works fine, so the problem might be with your base64 source.

Comment: Thanks onon15, byte[] K = Base64.decodeBase64((S.getContent()).toString()); and System.out.println(K); shows [B@eb7859. than is their any way to convert [B@eb7859 to Hellow World!?

Comment: You're printing a byte array. Read my answer again. This will print the type of the array and its hashCode. To transform a byte array containing encoded characters into a STring, you must use `new String(byteArray);`

Answer (score -1):

You must use this code

```
CMSSignedData signeddata = new CMSSignedData(signedBytes);
CMSProcessable cmsdata = signeddata.getSignedContent();
System.out.println(new String((byte[]) s.getContent()));
```

It work for me. 
I'm using BouncyCastle and trying to get original data from PKCS7 signed data.